# Redirect subdomain using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up a subdomain so that it will redirect to a specific file. EG. `register.mydomain.com` should show the page at `www.mydomain.com/includes/register.php` but still show `register.mydomain.com` in the browser.

The site is currently set up to not show extensions in the address bar eg. `www.mydomain.com/register` using the htaccess file as below and this works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register$ includes/register.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice here, is the files should be in same document root. This means, your .htaccess file and includes/register.php files should be in same root folder for application. You can then rewrite the rule -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^register\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ includes/register.php [L]
```

This might work, reload Apache after changing .htaccess files.